# using getUrl in a Magento shell script

Tags: shell, magento

I've created a script named `customscript.php` in the `/shell` dir.
This script extends `Mage_Shell_Abstract`.

When I use `getUrl()` inside this script, Magento adds `customscript.php` in the URL.

If I do:

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/view", array('order_id' => 123));
```

I have:

```
http://mysite.com/customscript.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/123/key/{secret key}
```

How can I remove `customscript.php` from the URL without using `str_replace()` the result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use '_type' param for getUrl() function as follows:

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/view", array(
  'order_id' => 123,
  '_type' => Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB
));
```

Comment: Working since more than 3 years daily with Magento and haven't this parameter until now! Thank you - saved me a lot of time :)